# asp.net visual studio 2008 not launching debug page

Tags: asp.net, debugging

I have an asp.net project in visual studio 2008

I press F5 and the "test page" does not launch and I don't understand why.

Looked at the properties for the site and "start action" is correctly set to "use current page"

Similar question. assuming it automatically launched above, how does one open a 2nd instance of the current debug site (seems like their ought to be a "launch site" button?

edit: I went back and launched VS as admin and it did launch the site. Maybe this is a security issue?

Comment: Sorry, not specific enough. No website is started. does not go to my default web browser and go to the debug website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart ur asp.net development server or try with some other ports. Go to solution explorer select the project -press F4 , then in the property window u can set the new port or try with restarting asp.net dev server